# Xcode - App installation failed: An unknown error has occurred

Tags: xcode

Eu atualizei o Xcode para a versão 7.2 (7C68).

Após a atualização eu não consigo mais instalar o projeto em desenvolvimento para testes em meu iPad.

Aparece essa mensagem:

> App installation failed: An unknown error has occurred

Eu já tentei dar um clean, mas sem sucesso.

Em um simulador o projeto é instalado normalmente.

Para fins de teste eu criei um novo projeto e o mesmo é instalado tanto no simulador como no iPad.

Tem algum log no `Xcode` para eu tentar achar o problema?

Comment: Exclui o app instalado no seu iPad e roda de novo

Comment: Já fiz isso. Gostaria de saber o motivo do downvote, quem deu poderia me ajudar a melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: Estranho, toda vez que aconteceu cmg eu simplesmente desinstalei e funcionou, qual o código de erro que aparece junto a mensagem?

Comment: @JefersonAssis esse é o problema, não aparece nenhum código, apenas a mensagem de erro desconhecido. Já tentei seguir o Technical Note TN2319, sem sucesso também. Tenho cocoapods no projeto, mas acho q isso não deve ser o problema.

Comment: Já tentou instalar em outro dispositivo?

Comment: Está rolando um problema com o certificado digital no xcode depois da atualização. Não sei se é o seu caso. Maiores informações aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932522/codesign-error-certificate-identity-appearing-twice/12633127

Comment: Ainda não testei em outro dispositivo. @CCastro esse não é o meu problema. Eu já resetei meu iPad e instalei a última versão do Xcode. Aparentemente o problema não é com o Xcode, pois estou com três versões diferentes e ocorre o mesmo problema. Estou achando que é algum arquivo de configuração, já que um novo projeto funciona normalmente no iPad. Eu não queria mover meu atual projeto para um novo projeto, pois não queria perder o track do GIT.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui fazer funcionar. Só que eu fiz tanta coisa q eu não sei como funcionou. Eu apaguei todas as chaves de desenvolvimento que ficam em Applicationn/Utilities. Removi todas as pastas que ficam em /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData e por fim fiz novamente um clean no projeto. Só que a cada etapa eu tentava fazer um build, até que uma hora funcionou. Talvez seja um bug? Eu vi que todos os relatórios estavam ok antes de instalar o app de debug no iPad e na tentativa de instalação aparecia o erro descrito nesse post.

Comment: Aconteceu novamente o problema. Apaguei novamente todas as pastas de /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData e funcionou normalmente.